# How to avoid duplicate rows while creating dataframe from scraped data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is just a simple code to extract dollar quote and variation. When exporting to excel I am getting an additional line with the same values.

How can I eliminate this double excel entry?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/.DXY'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

valores = soup.find('div', class_='QuoteStrip-lastPriceStripContainer')

cotacao = valores.find('span')

variacoes = soup.find('span', class_='QuoteStrip-changeDown')

variacao = variacoes.find('span')

print(cotacao.text)
print(variacao.text)

cotacao_dolar = []

for row in soup:
    dic = {}

    dic['Cambio'] = cotacao.text
    dic['Variacao'] = variacao.text

    cotacao_dolar.append(dic)

df = pd.DataFrame(cotacao_dolar)

df.to_csv(r'C:\teste\cotacao_dolar.csv')
```

Result:

[image]

Tried to remove duplicate but I want to eliminate the line directly from python code.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Just in addition to future posts. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are iterating `soup` respectively its two tags

```
<class 'bs4.element.Doctype'>
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

to create your `dict` and so append it twice to your `list`.

Remove the loop:

```
dic = {}
dic['Cambio'] = cotacao.text
dic['Variacao'] = variacao.text

df = pd.DataFrame([dic])
```

or may reduce script to:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/.DXY'

response = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

data = {e.get('class')[0]:e.text.split(' ')[0] for e in soup.select('.QuoteStrip-lastPriceStripContainer span[class]')}

pd.DataFrame([data])
```